# Get rid of `undefined` in a array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this function that receives params as an argument:

```
export const addCalculations = (params) => {
  console.log(params);
};
```

Then I want to access to the `id` value but when I do `params[0].id` it throws an error (Cannot read property id of undefined). When I see the console, that function is being called multiple times and it returns `undefined` sometimes. How can I get rid of those undefined and only get the last array?

[image]

Comment: I suppose you should check what is calling the function with no parameter and fix it there.

Comment: Don't access individual indices without checking if they exist. You've hardcoded `[0]`, so if none were passed, it'll throw an error when accessing the `.id`

Comment: You can check whether params exists before get the id. `if(params) {console.log(params); console.log(params[0].id); }`.

Comment: if (params!= null){
   console.log(params[0].id)
} it will check if undefined

Comment: The problem is the object itseld is `undefined` so when you call `params[0].id` it gives you exception

Comment: Notice that console is lazy rendered which means Object shown on console may not be the value when it printed. try `console.log(JSON.stringify(params))` to have a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[0]` itself is `undefined` so before going to call `params[0].id` you should make a check

```
if (params[0]) {
   id = params[0].id;
   ...
}
```

If you want to filter the array of params, you can use `filter` function

```
filterd = params.filter( x => {

  if (x) {
   return true;
  } 

  return false;

})

//continue with filtered 
...
```

Comment: that filter can be shortened to `x => x` or just pass in `Boolean` for something more semantically obvious.

Comment: correct, however I tried to make it more clear and readable for users and for @Liz Parody